# Why does Preview mess up an image while saving it to OpenEXR?

Tags: dynamic-range, preview, bit-depth, os-x

I started with a JPEG:

[image]

... and saved it to OpenEXR (8 bits per channel) using Preview on macOS Sierra, which created an [image with a washed out look](https://ufile.io/5r0ge). For your convenience, I've re-exported the EXR to JPEG and embedded it:

[image]

Why is this happening, and how do I create an OpenEXR that isn't messed up this way?

Answer (score 1):

OpenEXR stores its pixels in linear RGB, whereas JPG stores its pixels in a gamma-corrected RGB. (Technically JPG converts this to Y`CbCr before compression, but that's irrelevant to this question.) If you go to the "Tools" menu and choose "Adjust Color…" it will bring up the color adjustment window. You can adjust the gamma using the midpoint just below the histogram. If you move it to the right you should be able to get it back to the state you want.

Another way to show it how you want to see it is to go to the "View" menu and select "Soft Proof with Profile…" and choose "sRGB IEC61966-2.1".

Comment: Wouldn't Preview adjust this, like it does when converting RAW to JPEG? It doesn't produce broken JPEGs.

Comment: I would have thought that's what it would too, but perhaps there's a bug? OpenEXR is a very different format from others and it wouldn't surprise me to learn that it's less well-tested than other formats.